# Function to get a value json to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need help to get a value of a json for a function and pass this value of the function to the console, but now i'm recive var = undefined, follow the code below, thanks

```
var Site = {
    baseUrl: "https://www.usereserva.com/",
    visitUrl: "https://cloud-commerce-visit.oracleoutsourcing.com/"
}

var prodAPI = Site.baseUrl + "ccstoreui/v1/products/" + prodId;
var prodId = '0058597';

console.log("============= SCRIPT CALLCAPRODUCT ==============");
console.log("url API: " + prodAPI);
console.log("Id buscada: " + prodId);

var request = require('request');
var price;

function prodPrice() {
    request(Site.baseUrl + "ccstoreui/v1/prices/" + prodId, function (error, response, body) {
        var corpo = JSON.parse(body);
        price = corpo['sale'];
        console.log(price);  // result 169
    });
}
console.log("preço:  " + prodPrice());
console.log("Requisição CALLPRODUCT foi bem sucedida");
console.log("================================================");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using prodId variable before assigning the value to prodId. This will return error. Here hoisting will take place. Your code will be compiled as

```
  var Site = {
    baseUrl: "https://www.usereserva.com/",
    visitUrl: "https://cloud-commerce-visit.oracleoutsourcing.com/"
}
var prodId ; 
var prodAPI = Site.baseUrl + "ccstoreui/v1/products/" + prodId; // so here 
// prodId is undefined,thats why error. 
prodId = '0058597';

console.log("============= SCRIPT CALLCAPRODUCT ==============");
console.log("url API: " + prodAPI);
console.log("Id buscada: " + prodId);

var request = require('request');
var price;

function prodPrice() {
    request(Site.baseUrl + "ccstoreui/v1/prices/" + prodId, function (error, response, body) {
        var corpo = JSON.parse(body);
        price = corpo['sale'];
        console.log(price);  // result 169
    });
}
console.log("preço:  " + prodPrice());
console.log("Requisição CALLPRODUCT foi bem sucedida");
console.log("================================================");
```

initialize and assign the prodId variable first and then use it

```
var prodId =  "0058597";
var prodAPI = Site.baseUrl + "ccstoreui/v1/products/" + prodId;
```

Another one is that you are not returning any value from `prodPrice()` method and default return is `undefined`.
return the required value from method.

Please read about hoisting in java script. this will help [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 0):

Use Let or const instead of var to avoid such problems.

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75